# Sublime Text 2 plugin won't show up in Command Platte

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I started writing a Plugin for **Sublime Text 2**.

I created a new folder in "Packages/RailsQuick"

And Created 2 files:

**RailsQuick.py**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class GeneratorsCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
  def run(self):
    self.window.show_quick_panel(["test"], None)
```

**RailsQuick.sublime-commands**

```
[
  {
    "caption": "RailsQuick: Generators",
    "command": "rails_quick_generators"
  }
]
```

The problem is that i cant find `RailsQuick: Generators` in the Command Platte (CTRL + SHIFT + P)

[image: Sublime Text 2 Command Platte]

Console logs after saving both files:

```
Writing file /home/danpe/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/RailsQuick/RailsQuick.py with encoding UTF-8
Reloading plugin /home/danpe/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/RailsQuick/RailsQuick.py
Writing file /home/danpe/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/RailsQuick/RailsQuick.sublime-commands with encoding UTF-8
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check console output for possible syntax errors and such?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yes, no syntax errors.. added sceenshot.

Comment: Can you paste full console log text as text formatted using stackoverflow.com code formatting? I think we are missing something here.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help :) added console logs after saving both files.

Comment: Looks like the console logs are still not complete or have nothing relevant - please pate the full console logs (use the scrollbar)?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa i opened new instance of the SublimeText opened the folder, opened console using **CTRL + `** then saved both files, and pasted the whole console.. anything else i need to find there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My lucky guess:

Your class name is wrong. `GeneratorsCommand` should match the one defined in `RailsQuick.sublime-commands` (`rails_quick_generators`). Sublime Text 2 needs to have 1:1 mapping between these names, otherwise it cannot know which plug-in belongs to which shortcut.

Example:

https://github.com/witsch/SublimePythonTidy

Comment: Thanks! It's importent to add that the class name can also be:
**RailsQuickGeneratorsCommand**.